# Frequency Change with Tape Speed

Tags: signal-processing

I recorded my own voice in an old tape recorder. When I put the device in fast forward mode my voice turned a little squeaky. I wonder if the fundamental frequency of the voice had changed? Is that possible?

Comment: Check out [*Methods Section and Acoustic Manipulations Section*](http://www.voiceresearch.org/pdf/feinberg_et_al_2005.pdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.  If it is playing faster, that is outputting the analog value that used to be at time $t$ at time $t/a$ with $a \gt 1$, for some constant value $a$, all the frequencies have been multiplied by $a$.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot the time and frequency scaling property of the Fourier Transform: F{s(t/a)}(f) = a * S(a*f), for a>1